# Python Equivalent to Matlab's Movvar function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matlab

What is the python equivalent of the matlab function **movvar(A,[kb kf])?**
I don't think the pandas rolling function provide a functionality where the window of length kb+kf+1 that includes the element in the current position, kb elements backward, and kf elements forward.

Comment: You could set the window size and then use `.shift()` to adjust it as you want

Answer (score 1):

Without being about to test on matlab, I believe this should be equivalent to `movvar(A,[4 2])` in this simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[ 8.0, 4.8, 3.1, 5.3, 6.6, 5.7, 7.3, 4.9, 5.4, 5.7, 4.7, 8.1, 7.5]})
df['var'] = df['A'].rolling(7, center=False,axis=0).var().shift(-2)
```

Comment: Why is it .rolling(7, ...)? Should it be .rolling(4, ...)?

Comment: The window height is 7 right?  4 before, 2 after and one in the middle

Comment: I tried using 

`movvar(DNB_log,[3 3])` on my [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eeH_Dx2BLiibNfQBuyu5s_UEhn73iX41/view?usp=sharing) and it produced a different result with 

`test.rolling(7, center=False, axis=0, min_periods=3).var().shift(-3)`

Comment: check the [degrees of freedom](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) used, Pandas has `ddof=1` by default, perhaps try `var(ddof=0)`

Comment: ddof=1 produced very similar results, however the last 3 rows shoed NaN values :((

Comment: The treatment at the ends could very well be different - if you are asking for a window height of 7 but only providing 4 numbers how is it being handled in matlab?

Comment: I only used `movvar(DNB_log,[3 3])` in Matlab for the same dataset. While both python `test.rolling(7, center=False, axis=0, min_periods=3).var().shift(-3)` and matlab produced similar results, the only difference is in python, the last three rows are in Nan.